# Error when using glob, os to read csv files using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read multiple csv files in a directory, using pandas. I used two methods, and both are not working.

```
import os
from glob import glob
from math import*
from numpy import*
from pandas import*


path = '/Volumes/File/Names/Stuff 2016'


for filename in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
    qu = read_csv(filename, delimiter = ';', header = 0, skiprows = 24, nrows=2)
    print(qu)
```

Edit:(The above code works.)
Below when I try to just read all files in that specific path, without specifying it's a csv:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    q = read_csv(filename, delimiter = ';', header = 0, skiprows = 24,  nrows=2)

FileNotFoundError: File b'STD_20160103.00.csv' does not exist
```

This error is confusing me, since that specific file does exist in the directory. I'm wondering if the file names '*.00.csv' are the problem, but I just want to print the values along all the files, and it's not working. Thanks

Comment: Put a `print(filename)` statement in just before the `read_csv` and you will see what's wrong.

Comment: I see, I understand when referring to just filename in the directory, it doesn't give the full extension of the file, so it can't be found. Need to join path and filename, as suggested by answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob` returns the full path ... `os.listdir` only returns the filenames

so change it to

```
q = read_csv(os.path.join(path,filename),...
```

Comment: When I do this, it gives an error in reading the csv. So I go ahead and join path and filename before reading the csv, like I did above; 'for filename in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):'. This time this works for some reason. But yes I get the idea.